# Creating 3 children with fork

Tags: linux, pipe, fork

What I want to do is to create this kind of communication with pipes:

```
      1
    /   \
   3     2
    \   /
      4
```

So there should be 3 children.The parent sends something to the first and second child. The first and second child after they're done with their work they send the result to the third child.The third child prints the data sent.

Could someone tell me in theory or show me a simple example of how should this look?

Comment: The parent creates four pipes and then forks three children.  The parent and children then each close all the pipe ends they themselves will not use.  The four processes write / and or read to the remaining open pipe ends as appropriate.  Depending on its specific requirements, the third child might or might not need to use `select()` or `poll()` to help it handle demultiplexing its input without unneeded blocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pipe is just a channel between a sender and a receiver. As you want 2 and 3 to be able to send something to 4, the pipes for 4 must have been created in 1 (else, 4 should be a direct child of both 2 and 3 which is not possible.

So IHMO here is how that could be implemented:

1. program starts
2. it create all pipes: 1-2, 1-3, 2-4, 3-4
3. if forks first time. Let child call routine for 4:

   - close all unused pipes
   - read from 2-4 until eof
   - print
   - read from 3-4 until eof
   - print
   - exit
4. forks second time. Let child call routine for 3:

   - close all unused pipes
   - read from 1-3 (only required data or until eof)
   - do its job
   - write to 3-4
   - close pipe
   - exit
5. forks third time. Let child call routine for 2 - it is the same as 3 except that is uses 2-4 instead of 3-4, and so unused pipes to close are not the same
6. close all unused pipes
7. write some data to 1-2 and closes its part of the pipe
8. write some data to 1-3 and closes its part of the pipe
9. wait for all its children (this part is optional)
10. exit

The order of many of the above can be changed. You must simply create pipe first, do not close any pipe before all processes are forked and (wait and) close last.